# azure-ad-jwt how does it validate the token

Tags: node.js, jwt, azure-active-directory

I am using azure-ad-jwt in a node app to validate a token.  How does it validate the token, what settings does it use?  I am simply using

```
var aad = require('azure-ad-jwt');
aad.verify(jwtToken, null, function(err, result) {
if (result) {
      console.log("JWT is valid");
} else {
      console.log("JWT is invalid: " + err);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

JWTs can be signed with a secret that is shared between the token issuer and resource server.  In other words, the resource server which consumes the token uses the same secret to verify the signature in the JWT.

But this is not the only way.  JWTs can also be signed using public/private keys.  Azure AD uses this method.

azure-ad-jwt takes a JWT, "hunts down" public key certificates and calls the jsonwebtoken.verify() function for each certificate it finds.  Each time, it passes the JWT and cerificate. This is how azure-ad-jwt can verify the signature in a JWT.